# Why classes in the same package aren't collaborating with each other?

Tags: java, visual-studio

I wanted to create a class named `Person` in package `com.bazlur.java`, then create object for `Person` class in another class named `PersonDemo` in the same package `com.bazlur.java`.
But the problem is when I run the code errors occur...
Can you please tell me, how I should solve this?

Error :

```
PersonDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Person person1 = new Person();      
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonDemo
PersonDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Person person1 = new Person();
                             ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonDemo
PersonDemo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Person person2 = new Person("Swarna",22,"*********");
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonDemo
PersonDemo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Person person2 = new Person("Swarna",22,"*********");
                             ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class PersonDemo
4 errors
```

[PersonDemo.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5CbS.png)
[Person.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxMPS.png)

Comment: You're compiling *from the java directory*. Instead, you should be compiling from the `src` directory... or ideally getting VSCode to compile for you.

Comment: if I compile from src directory it says, file not found. :-(

Comment: Well you need to give the path to the actual file from where you compile... `javac com/bazlur/java/Person.java` for example.

Comment: At the top of PersonDemo.java, add the statement:

    import Person;

Comment: @CodeMaverick: No, that's not required, and would fail. They're in the same package.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah! It's working..Thank you so much..:-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to compile multiple Java files for this.

```
javac Person.java PersonDemo.java
```

And the path to the files depends on your current location in the command line. So, if you are on different path, you will have to pass the location like `javac com/bazlur/java/Person.java`

Answer (score -1):

I think you  need to add

```
import com.bazlur.java.person;
```

to your personDemo class.

try it!